# cannot convert from class to 'T'

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
await ProcessBuffer<ChannelItem>(item);
await ProcessBuffer<SiteItem>(item).Wait();
await ProcessBuffer<SiteMailItem>(item).Wait(); 

private async Task ProcessBuffer<T>(ServiceBusMigratedItemMessage item)
{
    System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T> buffer = null;
    buffer = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T>();
     switch (type.ToString())
        {               
            case nameof(SiteItem):
                buffer.Enqueue(ConvertSiteMessage(item));
                break;
            case nameof(ChannelItem):
                ChannelItem truc = ConvertChannelMessage(item);
                buffer.Enqueue(truc);
                break;
            case nameof(SiteMailItem):
                buffer.Enqueue(ConvertSiteMailMessage(item));
                break;
        }   
    buffer.Enqueue(something);
```

It raises this error in line buffer.Enqueue
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Models.Sites.ChannelItem' to 'T'

or  cannot convert from 'Models.Sites.SiteItem' to 'T'

etc...

```
public class ChannelItem : CacheItem
{
}

 private ChannelItem   ConvertChannelMessage(ServiceBusMigratedItemMessage migratedItem)
{
}
 private SiteMailItem  ConvertSiteMailMessage(ServiceBusMigratedItemMessage migratedItem)
{
}
```

I don't know how to cast and enqueue the channelItem?

Comment: DoThis<T>() where T : class

Comment: What if the caller specifies a type for `T` that is not related to `ChannelItem`?

Comment: @PowerMouse That won't help.

Comment: `await ProcessBuffer<ChannelItem>(item);
private async Task ProcessBuffer<T>(Someclass item) where T: class, new()
{
    System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T> buffer = null;
    buffer = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T>();
    T something= new T();
    buffer.Enqueue(T);` variation could also use `where T: ChannelItem` if you're only using it with subclasses of ChannelItem

Comment: Not sure what you're after here.  Seems like you want something like `ProcessBuffer<T> (T item) where T : ChannelItem`.  But if that's the case, couldn't you simply `ProcessBuffer(ChannelItem item)`, use runtime polymorphism and dispense with the generics?

Comment: @Pac0: As you can see, that much code is unreadable in a comment.  If that's an answer, by all means post an answer with an explanation.

Comment: Why is this method generic at all?

Comment: How is the parameter actually needed here `Someclass item` ? this could be very relevant for a proper answer

Comment: Generic because I have 4 identical functions that I want to refactor and the only difference is Enqueue(ChannelItem), Enqueue(FileItem), Enqueue(SiteItem), Enqueue(MailItem).

And want to call:
 ProcessBuffer<SiteItem>(item, _bufferSiteItems).Wait();

ProcessBuffer<ChannelItem>(item, _bufferChannelItems).Wait();

 ProcessBuffer<SiteMailItem>(item, _bufferSiteMailItems).Wait();
etc...

Comment: Then derive from a base class and dispense with the generics.  `ProcessBuffer(BaseItem item)`.  Or pass a T to ProcessBuffer.  `ProcessBuffer<T>(T item)`

Comment: Well if you've created a `ConcurrentQueue<MailItem>`, how to you expect to call `buffer.Enqueue(something)` where `something` is a `ChannelItem`? (Bear in mind that `ChannelItem` is hard-coded in your method at the moment... so even if you call `ProcessBuffer<MailItem>`, you'll create a new `ChannelItem`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Since you already have`ChannelItem`, you could derive your `FileItem`, `SiteItem` and `MailItem` from `ChannelItem` and just use `ChannelItem` everywhere in your code above.

Answer (score 1):

```
await ProcessBuffer<ChannelItem>(item);
private async Task ProcessBuffer<T>(Someclass item)
{
    System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T> buffer = null;
    buffer = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T>();
    ChannelItem something= new ChannelItem();
    buffer.Enqueue(something);
```

The above is your original code.

Your code has:

```
ConcurrentQueue<T> buffer
```

so only "T's" can be put in the ConcurrentQueue

So you need either:

(1)

Change your ConcurrentQueue generic-type:

```
ConcurrentQueue<ChannelItem> buffer
```

or (2) you need to put only T items in your ConcurrentQueue

maybe you mean to code the below?

(note the change to "T item" in the method signature?/

```
await ProcessBuffer<ChannelItem>(item);
private async Task ProcessBuffer<T>(T item)
{
    System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T> buffer = null;
    buffer = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T>();
    buffer.Enqueue(item);
```

or (3) many you mean (and need) to "constrain" the Generic.

```
await ProcessBuffer<ChannelItem>(item);
private async Task ProcessBuffer<T>(T item) where T : CacheItem
{
    System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T> buffer = null;
    buffer = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T>();

    buffer.Enqueue(item);
```

See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

In the above microsoft URL, look for this code sample:

```
public static void OpEqualsTest<T>(T s, T t) where T : class
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(s == t);
}
```

(You've now edited your question)

or 4

you may need a "marker" interface.

```
public interface IMyMarker()
{
}


public class ChannelItem : IMyMarker
{
}


public class SiteItem : IMyMarker
{
}


public class SiteMailItem : IMyMarker
{
}
```

and now constrain T to IMyMarker

```
private async Task ProcessBuffer<T>(T item) where T : IMyMarker
{
    System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T> buffer = null;
    buffer = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T>();

    buffer.Enqueue(item);
```

Here's the bottom line.

If you define a

```
ConcurrentQueue<T>
```

you can put ~~only "T's" on it.

you can "constrain" the T's some, but you can never break the rule that "you can put ~only T's" on the

```
  ConcurrentQueue<T>
```

Comment: I have edited the question to better describe what I'm tryin to achieve

Answer (score -1):

```
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<ChannelItem> buffer = null;
    buffer = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<ChannelItem>();
```

Just change the T to ChannelItem

Comment: Obviously OP wants something generic. So replacing `T` by one of the possible types won't help at all.